# magento addImageToMediaGallery is not working

Tags: php, magento

i was trying to add images into magento products programmatically but no luck.

i find the function addImageToMediaGallery can do that but its not working

```
$p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

// save product 
foreach ($imgs as $k => $img) {


    $img_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). $img;
    if( !$k ) {
        $p->addImageToMediaGallery( $img_path , array('small_image', 'thumbnail', 'image'), false, false);
    } else {
        $p->addImageToMediaGallery( $img_path , array(), false, false);
    }
    $p->save();

}
```

what i know

- product is loading successfully i try `$p->getName()` and i get the title
- the paths are correct, images do live in `/home/tronixco/public_html/caskyco/media/temp_images/dji_phantom_4_drone_4k_hd_camerea_3_axis_gimbal_5km_range_with_28_minutes_flight_time_manfrotto_bag_pack_4_.jpg`
- **addImageToMediaGallery** is doing some work as it copy the images to `catalog/product/d/j...`
- in the admin panel product_edit there is nothing , like no image have been uploaded what so ever
- im running an external script and not getting any logs in var folder neither any error in error_logs files
- this whole code is running inside a function `product_add_images( $id , $images )`

magneto version is 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'bulkimages/101/';

$productsData = array('Purple-Crown-Ring-MFAS.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MFC.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MSAS.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MSF.jpg');

$productSKU = '111';
$ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);

foreach($productsData as $fileName){
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        $ourProduct->save();
        echo "done ";
    } else {
        echo $productSKU . " not done";
        echo "<br>";
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: just put in your root folder and enable error report

Comment: error reporting is on , and i first tried putting my images in the root dir but no luck

Comment: images put in media folder and check permission